# Insert ranking into column

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, derby

i have a following `PREFERENCE_SCORE` table

```
ID(int) | SCORE(Double) | RANKING(int) |
```

I want to insert into database using the following code

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO PREFERENCE_SCORE_ ( ID, 
              SCORE,RANK) VALUES (?,?,?) ";
String query ="SELECT ID,FPIS,FNIS FROM db_housekeep";
ResultSet rsp = stats.executeQuery(query);
while(rsp.next()){
    int id = rsp.getInt(1);
    double fpis = rsp.getDouble(2);
    double fnis = rsp.getDouble(3);
    prSt.setInt(1, id);
    prSt.setDouble(2, fnis/(fnis+fpis));
    prSt.setInt(3, THIS PART i dont understand)
    prSt.executeUpdate();
}
```

What should i add so the `RANKING` column is automatically filled by the rank of the data according to the `SCORE` column?

Comment: And what would be the numerical relation between the two columns?

Comment: What DB are you using? Are values in `db_housekeep` unique?

Comment: So, you want to everytime update whole Ranking column when score gets inserted to get the rank based on the score?

Comment: Are you sure you want to write it directly in the table? Maybe it would be better to get rank by query, no?

Comment: How do you do that,@ValentinMichalak?

Comment: the id from db_housekeep are the foreign key to id from preference_score @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn

Comment: Like this ? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/get-the-rank-of-a-user-in-a-score-table

Comment: @DonQuixote, you should better use `select` query and get it order by SCORE DESC to get the ranking

Comment: Which SQL database do you use ?

Comment: It's apache derby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this approach is not beneficial. It will generate ambiguous data for rank.
e.g. if we insert the first row with (score 99) the rank will be 1 and after it, we insert the second row with score 100 what is the rank? (according to runtime calculation rant should 1 but we have already 1 so what can we do?).
So, its prefer to use it only will select data from the table for showing.

Hopefully, you know the syntax as ( `RANK ( ) OVER ( [ partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause )`   )

Comment: Derby does not support window functions

Comment: If you want still sale workflow then we have a workaround that is efficiently costly

Comment: @MDanish if the table is just `id` and `score` and i want to show the rank in jTable, I had to use the `select`  query?

Comment: Check this. it may help.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778746/query-to-rank-rows-in-groups